# PHP-FPM SECURITY RISK?

Tags: php

I have installed php5-fpm to run it with lighttpd web server.

I checked the processes and I have seen:

```
root     10117  0.0  0.1 150252  4684 ?        Ss   20:17   0:08 /usr/sbin/php5-fpm --fpm-config /etc/php5/fpm/main.conf
lighttpd 10118  0.0  0.1 151536  6836 ?        S    20:17   0:00 /usr/sbin/php5-fpm --fpm-config /etc/php5/fpm/main.conf
lighttpd 10119  0.0  0.1 151172  6236 ?        S    20:17   0:00 /usr/sbin/php5-fpm --fpm-config /etc/php5/fpm/main.conf
lighttpd 10120  0.0  0.1 151260  7228 ?        S    20:17   0:00 /usr/sbin/php5-fpm --fpm-config /etc/php5/fpm/main.conf
lighttpd 10121  0.0  0.1 150864  6820 ?        S    20:17   0:00 /usr/sbin/php5-fpm --fpm-config /etc/php5/fpm/main.conf
lighttpd 10122  0.0  0.1 150864  6820 ?        S    20:17   0:00 /usr/sbin/php5-fpm --fpm-config /etc/php5/fpm/main.conf
lighttpd 10123  0.0  0.1 150776  5580 ?        S    20:17   0:00 /usr/sbin/php5-fpm --fpm-config /etc/php5/fpm/main.conf
lighttpd 10124  0.0  0.1 150776  6576 ?        S    20:17   0:00 /usr/sbin/php5-fpm --fpm-config /etc/php5/fpm/main.conf
lighttpd 10125  0.0  0.1 150776  5580 ?        S    20:17   0:00 /usr/sbin/php5-fpm --fpm-config /etc/php5/fpm/main.conf
lighttpd 10126  0.0  0.3 154036 13952 ?        S    20:17   0:01 /usr/sbin/php5-fpm --fpm-config /etc/php5/fpm/main.conf
lighttpd 10127  0.0  0.1 150776  6576 ?        S    20:17   0:00 /usr/sbin/php5-fpm --fpm-config /etc/php5/fpm/main.conf
lighttpd 10128  0.0  0.1 150864  6736 ?        S    20:17   0:00 /usr/sbin/php5-fpm --fpm-config /etc/php5/fpm/main.conf
lighttpd 10129  0.0  0.1 150776  6580 ?        S    20:17   0:00 /usr/sbin/php5-fpm --fpm-config /etc/php5/fpm/main.conf
lighttpd 10130  0.0  0.2 152728 10864 ?        S    20:17   0:00 /usr/sbin/php5-fpm --fpm-config /etc/php5/fpm/main.conf
lighttpd 10131  0.0  0.1 150248  4116 ?        S    20:17   0:00 /usr/sbin/php5-fpm --fpm-config /etc/php5/fpm/main.conf
lighttpd 10132  0.0  0.1 150248  4116 ?        S    20:17   0:00 /usr/sbin/php5-fpm --fpm-config /etc/php5/fpm/main.conf
lighttpd 10133  0.0  0.1 150776  6496 ?        S    20:17   0:00 /usr/sbin/php5-fpm --fpm-config /etc/php5/fpm/main.conf
lighttpd 10135  0.0  0.1 150248  4116 ?        S    20:17   0:00 /usr/sbin/php5-fpm --fpm-config /etc/php5/fpm/main.conf
lighttpd 10136  0.0  0.1 150248  4116 ?        S    20:17   0:00 /usr/sbin/php5-fpm --fpm-config /etc/php5/fpm/main.conf
lighttpd 10137  0.0  0.1 150248  4116 ?        S    20:17   0:00 /usr/sbin/php5-fpm --fpm-config /etc/php5/fpm/main.conf
lighttpd 10138  0.0  0.1 150248  4116 ?        S    20:17   0:00 /usr/sbin/php5-fpm --fpm-config /etc/php5/fpm/main.conf
```

all the processes run with the user I set, but the first of the list run as root.
should it be a problem?

Thank you

Comment: That's probably just the master process.

Comment: Oh and please, no need to write all uppercase in the title.

Comment: It is my understanding that this is expected behavior.  The first HTTPD process then spawns child processes which run as the desired user.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is the expected and desired behavior. The primary process respawns all the children process and handles sending requests to other processes, it doesn't ever execute your PHP code so therefore has no security implications as such.

Answer (score 0):

Parent process usually runs as root user.
It spawns all other children that you see.
nothing to worry.